# schedule reports in Crystal Server

Tags: crystal-reports-server

I’ve downloaded and installed both Crystal Report 2016 & Crystal Server 2016 solution as free trials.

After configure the job server – for schedule to sending report by email (on CMS console), unfortunately I do not get any email from my Crystal Server when set as schedule.

Whereas the status of due scheduled report is ‘Success’, but by right click on due file and send it direct to email, its work!.

Whether this is related to using the trials version or what?

Comment: After you've scheduled a job, you can go into History and see the status. If you get success, you've either misconfigured e-mail scheduling, or transmission to the e-mail address is not working.

Comment: but when I send the file to email by right click on it (instead of schedule), its work and I can receive that file on my mailbox!

Comment: So, if you right click on the report and select History, don't you see the report scheduled? You should see a red ! next to the scheduled job that failed. http://imgur.com/rESiadf - The job needs to be scheduled, then it also has to run. Schedule the report for a past date and it should run right away.